# Upload pdfmake buffer to s3

Tags: node.js, pdf, amazon-s3, pdfmake

How can I upload a pdf I have created in pdfmake to s3?

When I upload my pdf to S3 using the below code I get a file created, but when I open the file it is a blank pdf. I know my document definition creates a proper pdf as I can output it to the console and verify it on the pdfmake site.

```
    pdfMake.createPdf(dd).getBuffer((buffer) => {
      var s3 = new AWS.S3()

      s3.putObject({
            Bucket: s3UserFilesBucket,
            Key: 'filename.pdf',
            Body: buffer.toString('binary')
      }, function (resp) {

      })
    })
```

When I open the file which gets created in s3 in notepad++ it 'looks' like a proper pdf. I.e. it starts with

%PDF-1.3

and has lots of special characters.

If I copy the document definition to pdfmake playground and save the pdf, and again view it in notepad++ it looks similar to the one I get saved in s3, the readable text is the same, but the special character blocks are different

Comment: Hi. Can you try with another generic file to see if there is some issue specifically with pdfMake or something wrong in the way you upload?

Answer (score 5):

Use a buffer and then pass the same buffer as an argument to AWS s3.putObject function. The following code will upload correct content of a pdf file(generated by pdfmake) to the S3 bucket.

```
const pdfMake = printer.createPdfKitDocument(dd);

let chunks = [];

pdfMake.on("data", chunk => {
  chunks.push(chunk);
});

pdfMake.on("end", () => {
  const result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  var s3 = new AWS.S3();

  s3.putObject(
    {
      Bucket: s3UserFilesBucket,
      Key: "filename.pdf",
      Body: result
    },
    function(resp) {}
  );
});

pdfMake.end();
```

Comment: Hi, please post your question or what issue you are having with this code or we won't know how to help you.  Check out this link for info on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If your buffer size huge, you can't directly push that to S3 bucket, you need to write the file using fs and keep it in tmp folder then push that tmp folder to S3

This will convert your pdf doc content to buffer

```
    getDoc(pdfDoc, cb) {
// buffer the output
var chunks = [];

pdfDoc.on("data", function (chunk) {
  chunks.push(chunk);
});
pdfDoc.on("end", function () {
  var result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  cb(null, result, pdfDoc._pdfMakePages);
});
pdfDoc.on("error", cb);
pdfDoc.end(); }

const fileName = `/tmp/${event.executionId}.pdf`;
async generatePdf(filename) : Promise<void> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const printer = new pdfPrinter(FONTS);
  const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
  this.getDoc(pdfDoc, function (err, buffer, pages) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      fs.writeFileSync(filename, Buffer.from(buffer));
      resolve();
    }
  });
}); }


s3Key = `public/processed/pdfs/xyz.pdf`;
await generatePdf();
const fileBody = await promises.readFile(fileName);
const upload = await s3Service.uploadObject(BUCKET_NAME, fileBody, s3Key);
console.log(JSON.stringify(upload));

public async uploadObject(
bucketName: string,
fileBody: any,
key: string
): Promise<S3.CompleteMultipartUploadOutput> {
return this.s3
  .upload({
    Key: key,
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Body: fileBody,
  })
  .promise(); }
```